# react react-select default value not working

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-select

i'm using react-select, and i can't set the default first option of the select, i need it to be the option i get from the server fetch from database

this is my code:

```
export default function EditAccountPopup(props) {
  const thisVatId = localStorage.getItem('CusVAT_Id');
  const [selectSortCode, setSelectSortCode] = useState([]);
  const [accountNumber, setAccountNumber] = useState('');
  const [sortCodeValue, setSortCodeValue] = useState('');
  const [sortCodeObj, setSortCodeObj] = useState('');
  const [accountName, setAccountName] = useState('');
  const [accountType, setAccountType] = useState('');
  const [vatId, setVatId] = useState('');
  const [allData, setAllData] = useState();
  const show = useRef();



  const getData = async () => {
    const selectedNum = props.selectedRow.number;
    const selectedSort = props.selectedRow.sort_code;
    await fetch('/accounts/selectedAccountData', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({ thisVatId, selectedNum, selectedSort }),
    })
      .then(async res => await res.json())
      .then(async res => {
        console.log(res);
        setAllData(res);
        show.current = { value: res.sort_code, label: res.sort_codeName };
        setSortCodeObj({ value: res.sort_code, label: res.sort_codeName });
        console.log(show.current);
        setAccountNumber(res.number);
        setAccountName(res.name);
        setAccountType(res.type);
        setSortCodeValue(res.sort_code);
        setVatId(res.vat_number);
      });
  };

  // get selected account data from database
  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  const refSortCode = () => {
    return show.current ? [show.current] : null;
  };
```

my select:

```
        <p>*קוד מיון:</p>
        <Select
          // valueContainer={sortCode}
          // defaultInputValue={selectSortCode[3]}
          // ref={show}
          defaultValue={refSortCode()}
          // defaultValue={{value: allData.sort_code, label: allData.sort_codeName}}
          // value={selectSortCode[3]}
          // label={sortCode}
          options={selectSortCode}
          styles={selectStyle}
          placeholder='בחר קוד מיון'
          onChange={e => {
            setSortCodeValue(e.value);
          }}
        />
```

i tried to do it with useState but it return the object before useState update it. so i tried to useRef, it is updated immediately, but still the select don't show the default option, what am i doing wrong?
thanks